# Building a dynamic Web Site with XML

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to build a website, the service is so simple: It gets a document as input, and tries to replace each word of it with something that it keeps in the database for the word.

It also has a forum in which people can vote for the equivalents, and these votes form the basis of the main service.

I want to do it in XML way, meaning that in bottom there is an XML native database, and there is an XQuery engine in the middle layer, handling the requests and elections.

However, the problem is that although I've read a lot about each of these product, and also implemented some codes, I don't have any clue from where I should start.

I mean I don't know what should be displayed to users, and how I can pass the form to the XQuery engine in server side, and how I connect the XQuery to the database.

Comment: I think this belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's very hard to answer such a broad question in a forum like this. There are likely to be many constraints that influence your choice of technology and application architecture (for example, project timescales, budget, target throughput and availability, skills and resources available to you), and it's hard to say what choices you should make with no understanding of these factors.

Comment: This is not a great question as it kind of feels like a student asking for someone to do their homework for them.

Comment: Well, I AM a student, but this question is not in anyway related to a homework or something like that. The thing is that, as I said before, I had some experiences in all of these technologies, but I don't know what the big picture is. I designed two websites using PHP and MySql, but doing it in XML approach is a great myth to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three components;

1. An XML database / xquery processor.
2. A web server.
3. A scripting language.

**Examples**

1. XML database/processor: You could simply store your XML data as plain text files on disk, in which case you only need an XML processor eg. Saxon-HE. This is absolutely fine for data of less than say 1mb in size. Above 1mb you'll probably need a combined xquery processor and XML database eg. Saxon-PE, eXist DB, BaseX or Qizx. This [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database) page lists the major ones.
2. Web server: You're creating a website so you need a web server, eg. Apache, IIS or Nginx. In this context, the web server accepts an HTTP request from the web browser, then invokes the scripting language engine which in turn invokes the xquery processor. The web server then returns an HTTP response to the browser.
3. A scripting language to tie everything together eg. PHP, ASP or PERL.

I'm currently using this combination;

```
  XML Processor:  Saxon-HE
  Web server:     Nginx
  Scripting:      PHP
```

In the past I've used;

```
  XML DB & processor: BaseX
  Web server:         IIS
  Scripting:          PHP
```

and;

```
  XML DB & processor: eXist DB
  Web server:         IIS
  Scripting:          ASP
```

The trickiest bit is working out how to get your chosen scripting language to invoke your chosen xquery processor.

Comment: You might want to use a full XML database solution like I did with BaseX. XQuery everywhere and RESTXQ to build the Web app. I guess ExistDB can do the same thing.

Answer (score -4):

I think it woild be sooo sloooowww.... (I might be wrong, but I've never heard about any production-ready xml database).

Think twice: do you really need all this xml crap? Why not traditional relational database? May be key-value database?

Comment: If you've never heard of a production-ready XML database, then you're just showing your ignorance.

Comment: MarkLogic is a high-performance, high-scale XML document database.  What Alejandro and Mike said is spot on.

Comment: Well, the answer to your question is that there is NO perfect solution to web development, regarding the relational database and XML databases. If your data can be expressed better in an XML file, then you should consider implementing the whole thing in XML-oriented technologies. When one possibility for sure is having a relational database and build everything on top in XML, and have some sort of 'translator' between them, which obviously makes everything slow, and it's not natural.